# Select a row matrix of values based on search

Tags: matlab, select, search, matrix

Suppose we have a matrix and we want search into every row in the first column of this matrix for some value.  At the end, MATLAB saves the entire rows of the values that match the first column.

For example we have this matrix

```
A = [...   
1   0   0;
2   0   0;
3   0   0;
1   2   0;
1   3   0;
2   3   0;
1   2   3;
4   0   0;
5   0   0;
6   0   0;
4   5   0;
4   6   0;
5   6   0;
4   5   6;
7   0   0;
8   0   0;
9   0   0;
7   8   0;
7   9   0;
8   9   0;
7   8   9];
```

The desired result would be shown below if we were to search for the value of 1 along the first column:

```
B = ...
[1 0 0;
 1 2 0;
 1 3 0;
 1 2 3];
```

Comment: Uhm... what? Can you give us a small example of the expected output?

Comment: generally  I want matlab search for all value
means at first [1] than [2] than [3]

Comment: What does "all value" mean?  Do you only want to search along the first column? That's what your example implies.

Comment: "all value " means :search all rows and 
rows that have the element perfectly with all the elements show

Comment: Use `ismember`. I've marked an appropriate duplicate. The only thing you have to do after is use those indices to index into the first dimension of your matrix to get what you want... so `ind = ismember(...);` then `B = A(ind,:);`

Answer (score 0):

But, if you know the value you are searching for, why don't you just save its index instead of the real value? I mean, if you know you're searching for '5' on your matrix A, why don't you save its location in a new variable?

Now, if you want to present the complete row that contains the value...

There is a variety of ways to do so.

Suppose you have a matrix A and you want to return the rows that contain '5' elements.

```
% Define matrix A
A = [1 2 4; 0 1 2; 4 5 6];

% Supposing user wants to find 5
value = 5;

% This returns a matrix where 1 are the elements equal to value in 'A' matrix.
elements = (A == value);

% These are the indices of the elements
[row col] = find(ans==1);

% Creating new variable B with the rows that contains value (5 in this case)
B = A(row);
```

Comment: That technically should be `B = A(row,:);`  Doing `B = A(row)` would only select elements in column major order with respect to the first row from `1` up to as many rows as there are in the matrix. This would not achieve the desired result.

Comment: Yes mate. I was about to leave office and didn't attempt to that. Thank you for your observation.